# In the Shopify API, is body_html sanitized?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

When fetching a Product (and some other entities) from the REST API, there's a `body_html` property that contains HTML. Is that guaranteed to be sanitized, i.e. safe to render in a browser? If I uploaded HTML that contained a  tag, for example, then fetched that Product, would the returned body_html include that script tag?

Seems like it probably would be, but I can't find anything that says for sure.

Comment: Ideally someone would point to some official documentation that I failed to find. If I just "try it and find out", I'm relying on undocumented behavior that could potentially change without notice. Also testing whether script tags are removed wouldn't be a complete answer; there are other things that need to be checked to make sure HTML is safe. Really the documentation should say what tags and attributes are allowed.

Comment: Also it's possible that someone else has tried it before and could save me the trouble. If no one answers, I'll try some things add an answer myself. That would at least provide some information if someone else is searching for the answer. I want this information to exist online, even if it's not official documentation.